# customizing colors in d3.js zoomable treemap

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I wanted to customize the colors in **zoomable tree map**.

I am using

```
color = d3.scale.category20c();

.attr("fill", function(d) {return color(d.name);})
```

here the name(`d.name`) attribute can be red, green, blue or any color and I want to have color according to given name. as of my current code color is not coming according to name.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If `name` is the name of the colour, all you need is `return d.name;` instead of `return color(d.name);`.

Answer (score 3):

Since your dataset provides the names of the colors, you shouldn't need to use a scale at all. As long as the color names used in your dataset are [**valid CSS color names**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/named-colors-and-hex-equivalents/), you can simply set the fill attribute to the name directly:

```
.attr('fill', function(d){ return d.name; })
```